# Does Spring Save Relationship Data too in Rest Call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So If I have a User and a UserRole Table like soo..

## User Class

```
package app.repo.User;

    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;

        @Version
        private Long version;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String username;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String password;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
        private Set<UserRole> roles;

        protected User() {}

        public User(String username, String password) {
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                    "User[id=%d, username='%s', password='%s']",
                    id, username, password);
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Set<UserRole> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<UserRole> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

    }
```

## UserRole Class

```
package app.repo.User;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(String roleName, User user) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

The above example has a oneToMany relationship with UserRole and a ManyToOne Relationship with user.

My first question is... is it possible to save User and UserRole in one save like so...

```
userDao.save(user);
```

And second question is. How would I set that up in a JSON post call ? and how would this be done. This is what I am doing now

```
{
    "userId":"1",
    "userName":"RestMan",
    "password":"happy",
    "version":"1",
    "email":"restman@gmail.com",
    "enabled":"1",
    "roles": {
        {"user":"1","role_name":"ROLE_COOLGUY"}
    }
}
```

Otherwise I am thinking to just create a Model that saves the two separately in one method

Comment: The appropriate tag is JPA. Yes, it's possible, using the cascade attribute of the OneToMany annotation. Make sure that UserRole.user is not null.

Comment: well i have the annotation set `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")` in the User class. What about setting up the json data ? Say if I wanted to make a post call with the user and the roles included

Comment: The JSON data is irrelevant. What matters is the User object passwed to userDao.save(). Every UserRole of that User must have its user field set to the user being saved. And I know you already have the annotation. But it doesn't have any cascade attribute set. And that's what matters. Read the documentation.

Comment: Ok, in this example that makes sense for security reasons. So based on the controller being called. should define what type of UserRole that person has. Ive been searching. if you can point me in the right direction that explains that. that would be great.

Comment: am I setting the Cascade value in the UserRole table only or User table. Or is it what ever table has the OneToMany relationship

Comment: Quoting myself: using the cascade attribute of the **OneToMany** annotation. Read the javadoc. You want to cascade the merge operation from the user to its roles. So the cascade must be on the association user.roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the annotation like this : @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: In the UserRole class only ?